# Sum of cached memory and shared memory exceed total memory

Tags: linux, memory

When I run `free -h`, I get:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          251G       208G        43G       179G       144M       190G
-/+ buffers/cache:        17G       233G
Swap:         5.6G       5.6G       1.1M
```

How can shared memory(179G) + cached memory(190G) exceed total memory (251G) ? Can memory be count as both of cached memory and shared memory?

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Yes, apparently it can. See, for example, [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/406773) explanation from Red Hat. See the line: "Cached: Memory in the pagecache (Diskcache and Shared Memory)"

Comment: I voted to re-open this question because the answers to the duplicate target don't  answer this question or explain how "shared memory is also counted as cached"  -- as pointed out in sourcejedi's answer.

Answer (score 8):

All `shared` memory is also counted as `cached`.

`shared` memory is implemented using `tmpfs` internally.  `tmpfs` is implemented as a thin wrapper for the page cache, just without having any backing store (except that `tmpfs` is swappable).

---

`man free` does not explain this.  At least on my system (provided by procps-ng, last updated 2016-06-03).  Sorry.  All `man free` tells you is that `cache` is taken from `Cached` in `/proc/meminfo`.  If you read `man proc` (from man-pages, updated 2017-09-15), it has documentation for the fields in the `meminfo` file, but it still fails to inform you that `Cached` includes `Shmem`.

You can see this with an experiment.  While you have `free` memory (not `available`), you can create a file in a tmpfs, for example:

```
dd bs=1M count=100 < /dev/zero > /dev/shm/test.tmp
```

The result of this is that both the `shared` and `cached` figures in `free -m` increase by 100.

If you only have `available` memory, and do not have enough `free` memory to test this properly, you can create `free` memory by dropping as much page cache as possible, by running `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.  Of course dropping page cache can be very bad for performance.  Do not do this on a real server :-).